# Resizing html row

Tags: css, width, html, percentage

I have a table that contains a row and a cell.  The cell contains a label1, selectbox1, label2, selectbox2 and I want some spacing to increase as the page increases, so I have a span that's width is set to a percent.  However, when I do this it causes the content of that cell to go off the page and my scroll bar will not scroll over far enough to view the full content.

If I set the span width to ##px it works, but I need it to be a percent?

I'm not actually using `<label> and <selectbox>`.  I'm just using those as a reference to make it look cleaner and still be understandable.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label1/>
            <selectBox1/>
            <span style="width:10%; display:inline-block"></span>
            <label2/>
            <SelectBox2/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table
```

Everything has been set to width:100%.
I cannot give each its on cell because this page was poorly created (before me).

Comment: None of that is valid html

Comment: I know, it's just an example.  I am not using <label> or <selectbox>.  I just referenced those to definable terms so that I wouldn't take up more space

Comment: Considering  <label1/> and <selectBox1/> aren't valid, they will have no width, and therefore % wouldn't work.
Since px is static, it will be applied anyway inside `<td></td>` not inside `<label>`

Comment: Don't use examples with invalid code, it's easier to spot invalid code than the actual question then.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SiCurious/DTSXj/) with span set to a `%` width. It appears to work okay, is this what you had in mind?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <label id="label1">Label 1</label>
        <select id="SelectBox1">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
        <span style="width:20%; display:inline-block; border: 1px solid;">Span</span>
        <label id="label2">Label 2</label>
        <select id="SelectBox2">
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm needing the width to be a % so that it will grow and shrink with the page.  It works, however it is causing the cell to go off the screen and the scrollbar cannot reach it.

Comment: Ah, apologies, I misunderstood. I have updated code to use %ge. What are you trying to achieve? Do you want the labels, select boxes and span to all appear on the same line, with the `SelectBox1` on the left and `SelectBox2` on the right?

Comment: I'm wanting everything left aligned but as someone increases the screen size, i want the label2 and selectbox2 to slowly move to the right.  Argh, see what you have is what I have.  I think the person who wrote this royally messed this up so badly that the only way to fix it is a complete re-write  (and these pages are 1000s of line long lol)

Comment: ahhh, the div is not increasing.  Even though the table extends past the div that wraps the table, it won't increase it's size even though it's width is set to 100%

Is there a div setting I can set that will force it to extend to the full length of it's content and not the page width?

Comment: Ok, wow, it sounds like the structure of the page is more complex than I thought. I was going to say you could use some sort of fluid layout which will respond to the browser width, but sadly this is beyond my current CSS abilities. e.g. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/09/smart-fixes-for-fluid-layouts/

Comment: Haha that's what I want to do, but I was gonna do this for fun as a side thing for my company... It is no longer fun due to crappy HTML code lol.  Thanks for your input!

Comment: Ha! When side projects go bad, I know how that feels :) Good luck